# make a pen drive appear as a cd?

Tags: windows, autorun, usb-flash-drive

I have a .exe file in my pen drive sitting in a long chain of directories
(driveLetter:\dir1\dir2....\dir8\program.exe)
Now I don't wanna go through all those directories to get to the file and run it, 
Problem is that in Windows7, running a .exe file with the autorun.inf open command doesn't work anymore in pen drives but it does in CDs, that's why I wanna make my pen drive appear like a CD to windows upon insertion.
Please don't ask me if I'm writing a virus here, cuz I'm not.

Any ideas how can I achieve this ?
if making it appear as a CD won't work, is there a way to run the .exe file
(I know, this might be a separate Q)

Thank you so much for anything you can provide me with.

Comment: Theoretically, it might be possible to make a pen drive look like a CD drive by replacing the device drivers.  But it would be a lot simpler to write a program that waited for you to insert your pen drive and then ran your executable, and simpler still to follow Rhyono's advice.

Comment: @HarryJohnston:: Actually, first, I made an app that does exactly what you say, (in C#) it monitors any insertion of any kind of removable drives and copies all files (I specify the type of files) from the pen drive to a location that i specify. Now, I wanna do the exact opposite, I wanna put my program in the flash, and when I insert it, it copies all files whose type if specified by me, from a hard disk drive to the pen drive.
This is just to ease all copy operations that I do all day.

Comment: I want a solution that not only work for my PC, but on all PCs.
Your solution works fine if i install the monitoring app on the computer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Could you tell me more about this 'replacing the device drivers' .. I mean, how can i do it ?

Comment: The MSDN library has a section on Windows Driver Development, but there's really no point, since you want a solution that works on unmodified PCs.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a flash drive use autorun by having the autorun and exe file in the default directory (i.e.: not a dozen folders deep). That's how I've done it when installing W7 on computers without a CD drive.

Here's what Windows 7 autorun.inf looks like

```
[Autorun.Amd64]
open=setup64.exe
icon=setup64.exe,0

[Autorun]
open=setup.exe
icon=setup.exe,0
```

It's pretty straight-forward: the top one is for a 64-bit OS, while the bottom is for 32-bit.

Comment: with 'autorun' you just mentioned, do you mean autorun.inf ?
if so, then yes, i've tried putting the autorun.inf and the .exe file in the root dir of the flash, zip, nothing happened

Comment: I'm having trouble making this work too.  Could you post the contents of the autorun.inf file you are using?

Comment: I've already tried copying the autorun.inf from the Windows 7 DVD to a USB stick and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Are you expecting it to hijack boot up, or are you properly selecting it as the device to boot from? Or do you want to have Windows already booted up and when you plug it in, it pops up with the autorun option?

Comment: no, I don't wanna boot up from it, please read my conversation with Mr.Johnston, windows is already booted up, I just wanna start off my app upon inserting the pen drive (I don't want my app to appear in the autoplay) .. insert the pen .. the app does its dirty work .. after about 10 sec .. remove the pen .. swift&clean ..

Comment: Your title and question are referring to essentially what I've stated. What you actually want to do is bypass AutoPlay as well as not clicking on the drive. I do not know of any non-registry/control settings methods of disabling or bypassing AutoPlay on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2011, Microsoft has removed the autorun.inf option, so it will not work, not even if CD drivers will replace the current drivers. Both CDs and flash drives can't be automatically started without at least a prompt shown to the end user. That is for security reasons.